# Plotting boundary between more regions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an array that contains some results for a phase diagram, if I have three categories they might be

`phases = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2; ...
  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2; ...
  1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2; ...
  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3; ...
  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3];`

I would like to automatically draw a dividing line between these three regions so defined, such that the final image would only contain two lines - one dividing regions 1 and 2, and one dividing region 1/2 and region 3.

The best explanation is that I want an image lige this
[image]

but with the colored patches removed, and instead having only outlines around the three regions.

So far, I've tried using `contour(x,y,phases,[1 1])` and doing a single plot for each phase. This gives parallel lines along the boundary, and at points where more regions meet, I cannot take the average of the two values.

```
phases = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2; ...
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2; ...
1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2; ...
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3; ...
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3];

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:8, 1:5);

hold on
contour(x,y,phases,[1 1])
contour(x,y,phases,[2 2])
contour(x,y,phases,[3 3])
```

This gives the result
[image]

i.e., there is a line demarking the "lowermost" border of the region of 3's, and another that find the interpolated value between levels 1 and 3 to create a contour at the value 2. But for a phase diagram, this leaves the area between those lines empty.

I have also tried splitting up the array in a binary array for each phase and used `bwboundaries` with the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you add an image of what you're getting (with the code of how you got it) and an image with the wanted result? That would clarify your question much.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot take the average of the two values"? What is wrong with the plot of boundaries of individual phases?

Comment: Clarification added